# Taking values from 1 activity and sending to 2nd Activity

Tags: android

So for this I am trying to take 2 integer values the user inputs in the 2 EditTexts provided in the main activity and add them together. Then, I want the android application to switch to the 2nd Activity and in the EditText box there display the sum of the 2 values entered into the 2 EditText boxes from the previous(main) Activity.

I think I'm on the right track, but I'm not quite certain how to obtain the sum in the second activity. I've tried messing with bundles and such, but I still can't quite figure it out.

**Re-edited to reflect some suggestions. The 2nd activity still does not show the total...I'm thinking it's a conversion error of some sort.

***I'm almost positive it has something to do with the 2nd Activity..the first looks right to me

**PERFECT! It was a conversion error. Thanks all for the help :D

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void OnClick(View v) //android:onClick="OnClick"   added to activity_main.xml for this button
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Summation.class);
    EditText v1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText v2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);   
    int first =  Integer.parseInt(v1.getText().toString());
    int second = Integer.parseInt(v2.getText().toString());
    String sum = String.valueOf(first + second);
    intent.putExtra("sum", sum);
    startActivity(intent);          
    }
}
```

Second Activity Class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Summation extends Activity 
{
    //Second Activity 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);        
        String sum = (getIntent().getExtras().getString("sum"));
        EditText addsum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        addsum.setText(sum);

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign your `int` value straight from edittext. You need to assign the edit texts like

```
EditText eText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourfirstedittext)
```

and the same with your second. Then get the values

`int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(eText1.getValue.toString())`

and of course the same with the second. You can then add these two `ints` together and simply pass them with `intent.putExtra("sume, sum)`. Then get them in your second `Activity` with `getIntent()`

```
Intent ci = getIntent();
final int sum = ci.getIntExtra("sum", yourDefaultIntValue)
```

If you are passing as an `int` you will need to do it this way and get the `String` value of the `int`. But if you pass as a `String` then you are fine

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no findValueByID...unless you mean findViewByID. Or at least eclipse can't find any documentation for it or google.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I have 4 kids running around...that's what I meant

Comment: That looks better but I don't know that you need
`intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Summation.class)`
here. You should just be able to set that in your intent declaration
`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Summation.class`

Comment: It's just how I was taught :) I think it still accomplishes the same thing, although the way you said saves some space I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all is almost perfect, but adding values to bundle is pointless if you do not attach your bundle to Indent and this is the step you forgot :) So either add

```
    intent.putExtras( bundle );
```

or make your code not using additional code but rather look like:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    int value1 =(R.id.editText1);
    int value2 =(R.id.editText2);
    double sum = (value1 + value2);
    intent.putExtra("sum", sum);
    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Summation.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

That's so close! In your first activity remember to do this right before `startActivity(intent)`:

```
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Then at the end of the onCreate method of your second activity class try this:

```
String valu = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sum");
EditText addsum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
addsum.setText(valu, TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
```

Comment: I wonder what's so terribly wrong with my answer that someone had to downvote it? Could someone please point me out the mistake I made?

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what (TextView.BufferType.NORMAL) means or how to use it..which is why I didn't use your code but by no means do I think your answer was bad. If I had enough rep I'd take it back up as I'm not sure why it was downvoted lol

Comment: From the [EditText documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html): `Sets the text that this TextView is to display (see setText(CharSequence)) and also sets whether it is stored in a styleable/spannable buffer and whether it is editable.` The possible values for the enum are "EDITABLE", "NORMAL" and "SPANNABLE". I just picked one, but you can change it should you require some other functions from it. Basically the point was just to make the EditText to show the number. :)